# PayPal API - CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am using the PHP PayPal REST API for credit card payments and a sandbox account and I get this error:

```
PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection :
ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.

{
    "name":"CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message":"Currency is not supported",
    "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "debug_id":"308d4b24ea4b5"
}
```

The "information_link" they provide does not provide any information whatsoever about **CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED** and what I found on another page of theirs is "more than helpful": *Currency is not supported You are using a currency that is not currently supported.*

The problematic currency is NOK, while EUR seems to work just fine.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: [NOK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) is a valid currency code for PayPal. I'd say this is a question for PayPal staff, rather than a coding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your paypal sendbox account address zone. May be it's not valid for NOK. For more details you can check it here :- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

Comment: Indeed.. this was the problem. The sandbox account was US-based, so I created one from the sandbox for UK and it worked. I just couldn't find where to change this... Thanks for pointing it out.